# PHP Sessions - where are they stored and how do you change a different session?

Tags: php, session

If a user is an admin, I would like to have the admins to have the ability to logout users manually. This would require altering and/or destroying another user's session. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to determine the current session save path. Or you use a database as your session storage. I think this would be the easier way to delete another users session: [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

Comment: If I call session_save_path how would I use that to delete or change a session?

Comment: You would have to know the session id of the user to log out in order to delete the corresponding file. By default the name of an users session file is `sess_{$usersSessionId}`. Then you could [unlink](http://php.net/unlink) the file. But of course you'd need write access to the session folder. In my opinion the easier way is to store the session information in a database and then have a column containing the users id in order to delete the session easily.

Comment: For the file solution I'd also reccomend a database table containing all logged in users with their corresponding session id. I can't see any other choice to get other users session id.

Comment: Is there a way to get the error message from that, if errors are disabled? I'm doing: unlink(session_save_path().'\sess_'.$row['session']); - it's not halting the script but it isn't unsettingthe session...

Comment: Do an `if(! file_exists(session_save_path().'\sess_'.$row['session'])) echo "File does not exist";`. And do a `foreach(glob(session_save_path() . "\*") as $sessFile) echo $sessFile;` to see how your session files are named.

Comment: I think it worked but i'm getting weird errors. On one page print_r($_SESSION) returns array ( ) but on the next it's fine. both have started the session with session_start()... o.0

Comment: I ended up restarting my browser, all seems to be fine - the !file_exists does not trigger and this echos Match.: $sespath = session_save_path().'\sess_'.$row['session'];
foreach(glob(session_save_path()."\*") as $sessFile) if ($sessFile == $sespath) echo 'Match.'; - I am clueless :/ - (oh and the session isn't killed, btw.)

Comment: I assume you are using a database. So why not use a flag `logged_in`, which after the user logs in is set to `1` and on every page refresh checked if it is set to `0` (by an admin), then delete the users session (`$_SESSION = array();`) and if the user logs out manually set `logged_in` to `0` too.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to that, I gave up on this. lol

Answer (score 0):

by default session data is stored in the files, identified by session id.
so, you have to know user's SID.

you can store user's current session_id in the users table and check it with each page request. so, by setting this value to null, it will be possible to logout users manually, without playing with session mechanism

Answer (score 0):

session default store in local storage, but you can code it, so that the session store in the system database, and through that you can remove the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about the [save handlers for php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler)

By default the session is stored in files (as determined by the php.ini variable session.save_handler.

The location is decided by session.save_path.

If you want to store your sessions differently, you can use [session_set_save_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) and store them at your need. Perhaps in a database for a multi-server system.